# Half dynamic content background in css

Tags: html, css, layout

Sorry if the title is not too descriptive, but I didn't know how to put it. The problem is:

[image: layout]

1 and 2, are divs that only contains background graphics, and have fixed width and height.

I would like 3 and 4 to contains also background graphic, but with dynamic height. It means if there will be much content, 3 and 4 will be higher, proportionally to additional content. Also 3 and 4 should always touching footer.

I know that propably this is easy, but I have hard time to position 3 and 4 on its place. What is needed html/css structure for this or how to accomplish this?

**Added:**

[Base code](http://jsfiddle.net/4wERd/) - under areas 1 and 2, should be areas 3 and 4 that would join them with the footer regardless of size of content area.

Comment: can u copy code on jsfiddle so that we can update according to your need?

Comment: I added link to jsfiddle with some code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>There's probably a simpler way to do this, but it's tricky getting a column to stretch down to match the dynamic height of a sibling, and I often  resort to absolute positioning.</strike>

Make 3 divs for columns to contain  1) divs #1 and #3 of your diagram, 2) div for dynamic content and 3) divs 2 and 4 in your diagram.

Place these 3 inside a div (I gave this one an id of "all"). Apply a clearfix style to this container (style defined at end of my CSS). Apply position:relative to this div. You also need to set the width of this container exactly to contain the three columns (necessary to properly account for the 3rd, absolutely positioned column)

Fix the widths of each of the 3 columns according to your design, float the first 2. Make the 3rd, however, position:absolute. Set top:0px; bottom:0px;right:0px;

Then set the heights of the 2 divs inside with percentages according to the proportions you want.

My solution has quite a bit in it. so I've kept the code at jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/feaLC/5/

Adjust the amount of text in the dynamic content area to see how it works.

**UPDATE** -- completely revised based on asker's clarification:

I'd accomplish this by absolutely positioning a left- and right-colum, and then absolutely positioned the 2nd div inside each of those 2 columns to stretch all the way to the bottom:

See also: http://jsfiddle.net/feaLC/6/

HTML:

```
<div id="header"></div>
<div id="all" >
    <div id="leftCol">
    <div id="left1"></div>
    <div id="left3"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="content">text text text text text text 
            text text text text text text text text text text text text 
            text text text text text text text text text text text text 
            text text text text text text text text text text text text 
            text text text text text text text text text text text text 
            text text text text text 
    </div>
    <div id="rightCol">
    <div id="right2"></div>
    <div id="right4"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="footer"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#all, #footer, #header{position:relative;width:500px;}
#footer, #header{background:green;height:30px;}

#content{width:300px;padding:0px 100px}

#rightCol, #leftCol{position:absolute;width:100px;top:0px;bottom:0px;}
#rightCol{left:0px;}
#leftCol{right:0px;}

#left1, #right2{background:yellow;height:100px;}
#left3, #right4{background:DarkRed;position: 
        absolute;left:0px;right:0px;bottom:0px;top:100px;}
```

Comment: Looks like your solution doesn't work for left column or am I missing something? :/ Also - I would like to have divs 1 and 2 with fixed height in pixels. It seems to be insanely complicated for that simple effect :/ .

Comment: It's not clear to me how you want the left column to behave. As I read it, you want it to have a fixed height, while the central area can grow or contract. Or how else?

Comment: I meant that center area should grow, and also areas 3 and 4 should grow with it while areas 1 and 2 would have fixed height measured by pixels. Also areas 3 and 4 should always touch footer area and areas 1 and 2.

Comment: Thank you very much for that second take, this is exactly what I was looking for :) . Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

with little jquery.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>div align</title>
        <script src="Script/jquery-1.7.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {

                $('.flex').height($('#main').height() - 200);//200 height of 1 or 2 div (assume 1 and 2 div has same height)
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div style="width:800px; margin:auto;">
            <div style="height:100px; border:1px solid RED">Header</div>
            <div >
                <div  style="width:100px; float:left; border:1px solid pink">
                    <div class="sdiv" style="width:100px; height:200px; border:1px solid RED">div 1</div>
                    <div class="flex" style="border:1px solid Black"> div 3</div>
                </div>

                <div id="main" style="width:590px; float:left; border:1px solid BLUE">
                    dynamic content<br />
                    <br />text
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <br />text
                    <br />
                    <br />text
                    <br />
                     <br />text
                    <br />
                    <br />text
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <br />text
                    <br />
                    <br />text
                <div style="clear:both"></div>
                </div>

                <div class="flex" style="width:100px; float:right; border:1px solid pink">

                    <div class="sdiv" style="width:100px; height:200px; border:1px solid GRAY">div 2</div>
                     <div class="flex" style="border:1px solid Black"> div 4</div>

                </div>

                <div style="clear:both"></div>
                <div style="height:30px; border:1px solid GREEN">Footer</div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```